# How to handle irrelevant Queries in Chatbot

Tags: nlp, chatbot, bert-language-model, langchain, large-language-model

I'm very new to this field. what I'm trying to build is a llm powered chatbot.

Using RAG with Langchain to address user queries.

What I want is a chatbot that answer user queries in a conversational manner. The bot should not deviate from the role, even if user asks any out of context or irrelevant questions.

Build an Intent Classifier based on BERT to classify the user questions then route to LLM bu some challenges like managing the memory to have the flow in conversational manner like follow ups

Any thoughts here would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!!!